# How to pass table name as argument in a stored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to implement the below query in a stored procedure.

```
SELECT d.empno, d.fecthIdId, c.empno
FROM MyDatabase.myTable  a
JOIN MyDatabase.myTable b ON a.id = b.xid 
JOIN MyDatabase.Table2 c ON b.Id = cId 
JOIN MyDatabase.Table3 d ON a.bid = d.cid AND d.empId = _empId
```

Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `TestSP`(_empId INT,   _myTable VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

SET @mysql.SQL
= CONCAT('SELECT d.empno, d.fecthIdId, c.empno
FROM MyDatabase.',_myTable,'  a
JOIN MyDatabase.',_myTable,'  b ON a.id = b.xid 
JOIN MyDatabase.Table2 c ON b.Id = cId 
JOIN MyDatabase.Table3 d ON a.bid = d.cid AND d.empId = _empId');

PREPARE dynamicQuery FROM @mysql.SQL;
EXECUTE dynamicQuery;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamicQuery;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Procedure Call:

```
call TestSP(10, 'myTable');
```

Error:

```
  Error Code: 1113. A table must have at least 1 column
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with how you pass the table name to the stored proc. That @mysql.SQL seems more interesting to me. I would use a variable name without a dot there.

Comment: @Shadow, It's legit according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html and a quick test.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you show on MySQL 8.0.31. What does `SELECT VERSION();` return for your environment?

Comment: Provide the otput for `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` for all 3 mentioned tables.

Comment: I am not sure about the issue, but after dropping and creating the table fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'd debug your code.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `TestSP`(_empId INT,   _myTable VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

SET @mysql.SQL
= CONCAT('SELECT d.empno, d.fecthIdId, c.empno
FROM MyDatabase.',_myTable,'  a
JOIN MyDatabase.',_myTable,'  b ON a.id = b.xid 
JOIN MyDatabase.Table2 c ON b.Id = cId 
JOIN MyDatabase.Table3 d ON a.bid = d.cid AND d.empId = _empId');
/*
PREPARE dynamicQuery FROM @mysql.SQL;
EXECUTE dynamicQuery;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamicQuery;
*/
SELECT @mysql.SQL `built SQL code`;
END
```

```
call TestSP(10, 'myTable');
```

| built SQL code |
| --- |
| SELECT d.empno, d.fecthIdId, c.empno FROM MyDatabase.myTable a JOIN MyDatabase.myTable b ON a.id = b.xid JOIN MyDatabase.Table2 c ON b.Id = cId JOIN MyDatabase.Table3 d ON a.bid = d.cid AND d.empId = _empId |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/18NTwuzR)

Now copypaste this code into your CLI and try to execute it.